# RelativeLayout - dynamically repositioning a view

Tags: android

I am trying to do a simple task of moving a toolbar up and down on the screen, but it only works once. The toolbar moves on the press of a button to the top, but I cannot get it back to the bottom even though the message “move to bottom” appears. See the code:

```
    boolean toolBarAtBottom = true;

    private void moveToolBar(){
        LinearLayout toolBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lp.height = toolBar.getHeight();

        if (toolBarAtBottom){ 
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        }else{  
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            Toast.makeText(DrawActivity.this, "move to bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        toolBar.setLayoutParams(lp);
        toolBarAtBottom = !toolBarAtBottom;
    }
```

Any ideas how to make it do more than once?

Comment: Each time you move the toolbar you make a `toolBar.invalidate()`?

Comment: No, no change with toolBar.invalidate()

Comment: can you try calling toolBar.requestLayout() after too.bar.setLayoutParams, i am not sure the purpose of lp.height = toolBar.getHeight(), since you have added WRAP_CONTENT this can be ignored.

Comment: Do you want the tool bar on the top and bottom of the screen?

Comment: Sudan, lp.height = toolBar.getHeight() picks up the same height as it was set in xml. So, you are right, I could replace LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT with toolBar.getHeight() and optimize the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` instead of `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM`.  `ALIGN_BOTTOM` aligns the bottom of a view with the bottom of another view. `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` will move it to the bottom of its parent container.

Here is a link to the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html